# Why my values of dielectric function don't match litterature (For Yambo with Quantum ESPRESSO)?

Tags: density-functional-theory, quantum-espresso, condensed-matter, optical-properties, yambo

I try to reproduce the dielectric function as the picture bellow using Yambo code but the values that I have found in y-axis are so much bigger [-1000,1500] compared to literature. I generated the scf file using Quantum ESPRESSO then I used Yambo to generate the dielectric function.

I have doubts that the problem can be related to the occupations type and degauss value. Actually I used occupations ='fixed' in the scf , then when I changed it to smearing the y-axis values reduced a little bit but I'm still far from the literature.

Can someone clarify my doubts about that, please? And which occupations type and degauss value I should use?

PS: I already encountered same problem in other calculations like DOS.

[image]

Link of the paper from which I took the picture: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S092145260600189X

Comment: Could you please link or state the name of the literature that you mentioned where the picture is taken from?

Comment: @AbdulMuhaymin I added the link to the post

Comment: @AbdulMuhaymin I tried epsilon too and the values are always so high. Do you have any idea why is that? Or do you know the unit used by epsilon?

Comment: Did you get comparable result after rescaling the values as suggested in the answer?

Comment: @AbdulMuhaymin yes. Do you face the same issue when you calculate dielectric function?

Comment: not really, but I was following tutorial step-by-step, and reproduced exactly using their input files. So, it is normal. I haven't tried any independent calculation.

Comment: @AbdulMuhaymin Can you send me the tutorials that you were following please

Comment: I am following [this](https://books.google.com.tr/books?id=5pKdEAAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false) book. See chapter 3 section 4: Optical Properties. The source code can be found [here](https://github.com/nguyen-group/QE-SSP/tree/master/mos2/optic)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The plot in the reference paper is in the [Arbitrary unit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary_unit). So, the absolute value doesn't matter. The value can be 1 in the paper and 1000 in your calculation - it is not a problem. I think the only thing to make sure is that the overall shape is correct.

You can try choosing a suitable reference point in the paper, let's say $3  \mathrm{eV}$. Then reduce your calculated $\varepsilon_1$ value (let's say $6000$) at that point so that it matches the value given in the paper (looks like around $6$). Note the reduction factor (in this hypothetical example, it is $1000$). Then apply the same reduction factor for all of your data (i.e. divide everything by $1000$). Similarly, reduce your $\varepsilon_2$ data too. Then if you plot these reduced data, you can compare your result with the reference data.

Comment: I was thinking about the same thing but I needed someone to confirm to me if that's the right thing to do, thank you